# Right way to register Enterprise App in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can someone describe to me the differences in registering Enterprise Applications via

1. Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)
2. Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com, Home -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications)
3. Azure AAD Portal (https://aad.portal.azure.com)

Perhaps there are even others that you may know of.

Answer (score 0):

The application registered in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) is the v2.0 application, which supports both Azure AD & Microsoft Accounts. Works with MSAL & most 3rd party oAuth/OIDC libraries. Can call the Microsoft Graph, and your own web API with ID tokens. If you register an application using personal Microsoft account, the application won't be visible in Azure Active Directory. For more details, you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app).

While the application registered in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) is the v1.0 application, which only supports sign in with Azure AD accounts. Can call the Microsoft Graph, other Microsoft resources, your own web API. For more details, take a look at the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app).

There's a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison) describe the difference between the two endpoints.

As far as I know, the application registration is almost the same in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and [Azure AAD Portal](https://aad.portal.azure.com).

Comment: Thank you, I will do some more research.